# How to Emulate UI-Router Resolve in Directive?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui-router

In other words, how do I make calls and get data before I start displaying the html in the directive?

Or is the simple solution of having a variable indicating `$scope.isAllDataLoaded` and triggering an ng-if/ng-hide pretty much it?

Comment: In a directive you can use the  $compile service to render the HTML after loading data. To see how it is done, see the [source code for `ng-include`](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngInclude.js#L295).

Comment: I have considered it, but I thought it was more for compiling if you wanted to build custom html. Seems like a good solution though.